# How do I enable sticky keys In Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, accessibility

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. How do I enable sticky keys like in Windows?

Comment: If an answer is helpful to you then please consider marking it as the accepted answer so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out. See the [help center](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To enable Sticky Keys go to System Settings --> Universal Access --> Typing --> And click the Sticky Keys switch.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can also change it from the command line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard stickykeys-enable true
```

As well as the other two options:

Disable if two keys are pressed together:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard stickykeys-two-key-off true
```

And the beeps:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard stickykeys-modifier-beep true
```

You can disable each of these by replacing `true` with `false` in the commands.