# (alt) and (super) keys suddenly stopped working in gnome 3

Tags: gnome, xorg, keyboard-layout

For my daily work I use two keyboard layouts: The normal German Qwertz (`setxkbmap de`) as well as [Neo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Neo) (`setxkbmap de neo`). Yesterday suddenly between switching back and forth between keyboard layouts <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd> stopped working normally for window switching and accessing the gnome shell overview using Neo. More precisely with Neo:

- When any window has focus pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd> has no effect whatsoever (neither <kbd>Alt</kbd> - <kbd>Tab</kbd> for application switching, <kbd>Alt</kbd> - for window switching, or just <kbd>Super</kbd> to get to the activities overview).
- If now window is open <kbd>Super</kbd> works fine. The same goes for when I'm in the activities overview.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>Alt</kbd> - <kbd>F1</kbd> etc. works unaffected.

My system wide default keyboard layout is neo and I switch between keyboard layouts with `setxkbmap de` / `setxkbmap de neo` via a keyboard shortcut (the calculator button). When I switch to Qwertz everything works as expected.

I didn't find anything interesting in `/var/log/{syslog, Xorg.0.log, gdm/*}` and as far as I can tell there were no package installations at the time the problem started. I also tried removing the cache files `/var/lib/xkb/*` to no avail.

I'd also be happy about hint's how I can debug this phenomenon. As it it I'm at loss with what could be the cause.

**Edit**: If found a workaround: After logging out and logging in again everything works (my user get's automatically logged in after boot).

Comment: this bug is still there (as of Sep 2015)

Comment: Seems related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/451945/permanently-set-keyboard-layout-options-with-setxkbmap-in-gnome-unity

Comment: Keyboard may have inadvertently change state?  May be related to activation of meta-key-combos e.g: [Sticky Keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_keys)   Or bounce-keys etc. Related Q: https://askubuntu.com/questions/301733/how-do-i-enable-sticky-keys-in-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: you could try this. Install xfce4 as additional window-manager first. Then reboot and login via xfce4. Test there how keys behave. When there is no dis-order with keys, then you could de-install gnome with gdm. Then wait until gnome is improved again (4 to 6 months). After this you could install gnome again. If this does not work, might be that keys got sticky by untidy living ?!

Comment: This happens occasionally in kde.  If you don't wait long enough after boot things get messed up.  Hard to know what it is.

Comment: Voting to close as this appears to be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop and use sudo apt-get install bleachbit remove all Unwanted and install sudo apt-get install gnome-shell...ur done

Answer (score -1):

IF you go into the keyboard settings you should be able to rearrange them.. As well as that have you put a lil time into finding a possible external application that lets you use them in Gnome 3 for those alt and super keys? Sorry if this didn't help you much.