# Permanently set keyboard layout options with setxkbmap in gnome/unity

Tags: unity, 13.10, gnome, keyboard-layout, 14.04

Ubuntu 13.10<sup>1</sup> (and maybe upstream gnome) introduced [very annoying bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1244090): pressing keyboard layout switch shortcut makes focus go away to some system window, then back to window where shortcut was pressed. Some applications have some actions bound to change of focus, for example twitter (in browser) closes reply text input field when losing focus, etc. So ubuntu's native keyboard switcher isn't suitable for me, until fixed.

X has builtin switching mechanism, and it is much better, in addition to that it does not involve focus switching, it switches immediately (gnome switcher also sometimes lags).

How can I set up xkbmap options so settings will remain after reboot and will not be reset by Gnome?

### What I've tried:

#### First, just executing setxkbmap:

```
setxkbmap -layout "us,ru"
setxkbmap -option "grp:caps_toggle,grp_led:scroll,compose:ralt"
```

But it works only:

1. For current session
2. Until Gnome will overwrite it (for example touching something in gconf's `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources` triggers reset).

#### Second, adding xkb options to Xorg config:

Another option is to add following to xorg config:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "us,ru"
        Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
        Option "XkbVariant" "pc105"
        Option "XkbOptions" "grp:rctrl_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
EndSection
```

Xorg understands that during startup:

```
[    33.791] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    33.791] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    33.791] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ru"
[    33.791] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "pc105"
[    33.791] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:rctrl_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
```

But switching configuration still resets later, likely by gnome.

#### Third, gconf

[image]

I have `xkb-options` and `sources` set in `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources`, but Gnome still sets xkb to single English layout:

```
$ setxkbmap -print -verbose 10
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
options:    grp_led:scroll
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete+ledscroll(group_lock)
symbols:    pc+us+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete+ledscroll(group_lock)"    };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

#### Fourth, another option in gconf

[image]

Setting `org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard` also does not work for me. Nothing changes.

**Upd 1**: [There is discussion](http://anarsoul.blogspot.ru/2012/10/gnome-36-and-keyboard-layout.html) recommending to remove `/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/libkeyboard.so`. At least this fixes some resets of xkbmap (i.e. after lock screen).

<sup>1</sup> I use 14.04, but problem with losing focus is still not fixed. ([Unconfirmed report in upstream Gnome](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=700316))

Comment: Have you tried setting the layout correctly in gnome and then adding the two `setxkbmap` commands to your `~/.profile`? That way, they will be run each time you log in and since the same settings are there in Gnome, it should not change anything if it resets.

Comment: @terdon it resets even after screen lock. And it resets to "us-only, no switch" state, not to settings defined in ``org.gnome.desktop.input-sources``.

Comment: Strange. Are you _sure_ you are using Gnome and not Unity? Have you tried changing the settings through the normal GUI instead of `dconf-editor`?

Comment: @terdon yes, it is unity, but it uses lost of gnome's stuff, like gnome-settings-daemon, which possily resets keymap.

Comment: So, have you tried setting the correct settings from the Unity GUI?

Comment: @terdon unity GUI does not set xkbmap correctly, it uses its own switcher that intercepts keypresses and switch keyboard. It is slow and [causes focus to being loss when key is pressed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1244090).

Comment: +1 for the question. This is a really annoying (and ignored) bug. I ended up [designing my own layout](http://rlog.rgtti.com/2014/05/01/how-to-modify-a-keyboard-layout-in-linux/) to avoid switching layout; but I understand that it is viable for me because I need just a couple of keys but not a general solution. By the way, have you checked if disabling ibus helps? See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1246272

Comment: Sorry, the correct bug should be https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1240198

Comment: Something not related with your problem: Which theme is this?

Comment: Setting the `xkb-options` field to `['altwin:swap_alt_win']` in `dconf-editor` works in ubuntu 14.10 (unity) to have this xkboption remain after switching the keyboard layout (e.g. english -> french etc). In contrast, `setxkbmap -option` does't work for that, this cmd has to be re-issued each time. Not quite sure if this helps your problem - this is just to say that it appears that `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources` is what matters when the keyboard layout is switched (at least on unity)

Comment: `xmodmap` is possible solution although is certainly reset on restart.  This should set it to Dvorak `wget -qO- http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=t2Ndf1Zw | xmodmap -`

Comment: Found [`localectl`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg#Using_localectl) but it doesn't persist, either. Did you find a solution that persists after reboot and lock screen? I am looking for a command line, scriptable one myself.

Answer (score 21):

To prevent gnome resetting keyboard setting in X i use this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard active false
```

This works for me.

Comment: I tried this on Ubuntu 14.04 and it does nothing. Do you have any explaination re: how this is supposed to work?

Comment: Works for me in 14.04

Comment: Works for me in 16.04, after trying everything else.

Comment: The only method I found working in 17.04.

Comment: Keep in mind Ubuntu had actually created a unity-settings-daemon for a period of time as well, but now that they are going back to Gnome again this might keep working.

Comment: I'm receiving `No such schema org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard`on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 6):

I've been going nuts over this just like you, but with Ubuntu 14.04 (LTS),  Xubuntu, xfce 4.12 and xkbd (from xfce goodies). Ctrl+Space to change the keyboard layout worked, but Alt+Shift didn't (modifier-only keys).

Finally managed to make things work-

```
1. Run ibus-setup (Keyboard Input Methods application).
2. Goto Advanced tab.
3. Check 'Use system keyboard layout'.
4. Click 'Close'

5. Run xfce4-keyboard-settings (Keyboard application).
6. Goto Layout tab.
7. Uncheck 'Use system defaults'
8. Select 'Keyboard model' (typically 'Generic 105-key (Intl) PC' will do)
9. Set 'Change layout option' to your required switching keys combination (typically Alt+Shift will do).
10. Add languages to 'Keyboard layout'.
11. Click 'Close'.
12. Restart the computer
```

You're done! Use Alt+Shift to change keyboard layout.

Comment: Why do you recommend using `xfce4-keyboard-settings` in the question asking for help with gnome/unity, specifically?

Answer (score 2):

I just read [this article](http://blog.martin-graesslin.com/blog/2014/05/screenlocker-architecture-in-plasma-next/) on screenlocking, which may be related.  According to the article, screenlocking has the intended consequence of blocking input devices and manipulating locales.  Seems like you have a few options:

1. Stop locking the screen, probably this includes the greeting screen as well which serves a similar function
2. Use different power management tools
3. Stop using ibus for im-switching (Perhaps FCITX?)
4. Create a hook for screen unlock events as described [here](https://people.gnome.org/~mccann/gnome-screensaver/docs/gnome-screensaver.html#gs-signals).

There is an interesting discussion of this and related events which can be found on the ubuntu-dev mailing list: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2013-November/037768.html

Answer (score 1):

Workaround by user *wof* in Ubuntu bug tracker, for Ubuntu 14.10 using [gxkb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gxkb/):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1244090/comments/39

> this workaround worked for ubuntu 14.10:
>
> - in Settings->Text entry remove all input sources, leave only english
> - install gxkb (layout switcher): sudo apt-get install gxkb
> - add gxkb to startup applications via gnome-tweak-tool
> - setup gxkb hotkeys in ~/.config/gxkb (default is alt_shift, but in 14.10 it doesn't work. ctrl_shift works ok)
>
> p.s. new version of gxkb has appindicator for ubuntu. can be installed via ppa:zen-root/gxkb-stable

Comment: (Not tried it yet)

Comment: E: Unable to locate package gxkb

Answer (score -1):

> First, just executing setxkbmap:
>
> setxkbmap -layout "us,ru" setxkbmap -option
>   "grp:caps_toggle,grp_led:scroll,compose:ralt"
>
> But it works only:
>
> ```
> For current session
> Until Gnome will overwrite it (for example touching something in gconf's org.gnome.desktop.input-sources triggers reset).
> ```

Well as far as Gnome "resetting" it i dunno. I do know how you can get to stay every reboot though as I had to do the exact same type of thing for my Logitech mouse. It has multiple buttons which I wanted remapped a certain way and I had to have that set at restart.

So what you do for that is create a text file.
Then in that text file type:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

and right below that put in your commands. As example my mouse looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
xinput set-button-map "Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse" 1 2 3 4 5 8 9 6 7 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

next you would save that as whatever name you want and move it to some place like your home directory. it has to stay there "forever".

then just open up your Startup Applications and Add the file to your startup and then you dont have to worry about it lasting only for the session. it will be ok to reboot your computer because your settings will come back through the file you just added.