# Set keyboard layout to de, variant us

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I want to set my keyboard layout to 'de' variant 'us'. On my ubuntu 15.10 with unity this works fine using the command `setxkbmap de us`.

The problem is, I have to run this command after every boot/after every wakeup from sleep. How can I configure my system to permanently use the mentioned layout? I know I can use some form of autostart (unity's or .xinitrc), however this won't work after suspend. I also read about setting the layout in org.gnome.desktop.input-sources [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672065/xorg-conf-keyboard-layout-lost-when-window-manager-starts), but this won't give the desired results using the string 'de+us'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity: how does that layout look like? (Umlauts?,qwertz? but / directly accessible ?)

Comment: It basically is a us qwerty keyboard layout with the german umlauts on AltGr+o/u/a/s and on AltGr+*where they would be on a german layout*. For me this layout combines easy access to the braces, /, .. and the german umlauts. It just feels more natural than using e.g. the compose functionality or switching between layouts. If only I could get ubuntu/X to use it by default :[.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note for other searchers landing on this page: this is apparently peculiar to the `de-us` layout in the Unity environment, because for some reason it lacks an entry in a particular configuration file.

---

**How keyboard data is stored in Ubuntu**

In Ubuntu, there is a folder called `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` which contains a few subfolders as well as a number of text files, each representing a different layout.  Most, if not all, of these layouts, have a number of variants.  The one we're interested in is the `us` variant of the `de` keyboard, so we open the file `de` and scroll down to the following entry (it was at line 686 for me, but I'm not on 15.10).

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "us" {
    include "us"

    name[Group1]="German (US keyboard with German letters)";

    key <AC01> { [           a,          A, adiaeresis, Adiaeresis ] };
    key <AC02> { [           s,          S,     ssharp,     ssharp ] };
    key <AC10> { [   semicolon,      colon, odiaeresis, Odiaeresis ] };
    key <AC11> { [  apostrophe,   quotedbl, adiaeresis, Adiaeresis ] };
    key <AD03> { [           e,          E,   EuroSign,   EuroSign ] };
    key <AD07> { [           u,          U, udiaeresis, Udiaeresis ] };
    key <AD09> { [           o,          O, odiaeresis, Odiaeresis ] };
    key <AD11> { [ bracketleft,  braceleft, udiaeresis, Udiaeresis ] };
    key <AE03> { [           3, numbersign,    section,    section ] };
    key <AE11> { [       minus, underscore,     ssharp,   question ] };

    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
};
```

This defines the keyboard to be identical to the standard QWERTY variety `us`, with changes to

- keys 1 (A), 2 (S), 10 (;), and 11 (') on the home row
- keys 3 (E), 7 (U), 9 (O), and 11 ([) on the top row
- keys 3 (3) and 11 (-) on the numbers row
- the ALT key used to access the special characters

We check that it's properly formatted, not missing any brackets or anything, and it is.  This is why `setxkbmap de us` succeeds, if only temporarily.  We'll copy the description from this entry later on.

**How Ubuntu accesses that data**

Ubuntu has a registry setting where it saves the name of the keyboard or keyboards the user wants.  However, we have to fix an entry in another configuration file before Ubuntu will accept our preferred keyboard.  The file that needs to be modified is `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`.

This file has three major sections:

- a list of known keyboard models (describing the physical arrangement of buttons)
- a list of known keyboard layouts (describing the logical assignment of characters to keys)
- a list of options (describing possible modifications to the layout)

We need to open this as root so we can save it later.  Since we want to use the `us` variant of the `de` layout, the relevant portion of the file is going to be the second section- specifically, we modify the German layout (in my copy, this begins on line 3176).

```
<layout>
  <configItem>
    <name>de</name>

    <shortDescription>de</shortDescription>
    <description>German</description>
    <languageList>
      <iso639Id>ger</iso639Id>
    </languageList>
  </configItem>
  <variantList>
    <variant>
      <configItem>
        <name>us</name>
        <description>German (US keyboard with German letters)</description>
      </configItem>
    </variant>
```

Notice the structure of this section.  Each layout contains a configuration and multiple variants.  I've added a new `variant` entry (the last six lines), immediately after the tag opening `variantList`, the content of which matches what I found in the keyboard data file above.

After saving, change the registry setting to select our newly added entry:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources [('xkb', 'de+us')]
```

I found it necessary to log out and back in for this change to take effect, but after that, the layout worked as one would hope, including surviving suspend/resume cycles.

Comment: Awesome,  thanks for the background info! This is exactly what I was looking for. I will open a bug report and try get this fixed in future unity versions. Btw is there any sort of documentation where stuff like this is described?

Comment: The documentation is not comprehensive; I synthesised my answer from a number of different sources and some experimentation on a LiveUSB.  My take is, if you're offering a bounty you deserve a thorough response.

Comment: I did this on Debian too. Thanks for the documentation. For me the new `German (US keyboard with German letters)`-variant was selectable via the `Region & Language` settings after editing the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`. But a logout-login between these steps was required.

Answer (score 1):

Add new script into `/etc/pm/sleep.d`, name it `20_my-layout`

```
case "${1}" in
    resume|thaw)
        DISPLAY=:0.0 ; export DISPLAY
        setxkbmap de us
;;
esac
```

**Source:** [How to execute a command after resume from suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/a/92235/26246)

Comment: This is a clever answers aswell. Thanks, I was not aware of the sleep.d folder!

Answer (score 0):

TL:DR add the command

```
setxkbmap de us
```

in the files `~/.gnomerc` and `~/.zshrc`.

Found this solution while I implemented the [detailed solution provided by Aoeuid](https://askubuntu.com/a/724004). During this I stumbled over the already existing `'de(us)'`-Section in the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/de` that contains almost the same configuration as listed in Aoeuid's solution.

This section is also part of the solution described at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/589273

About my environment

```
Debian 11.2.0 (Bullseye), 64-bit
GNOME Version 3.38.5
Windowing System X11
```