# How do I display X keyboard layout?

Tags: unity, xorg, keyboard-layout, gsettings

In Ubuntu 14.04, I am switching keyboard layouts with X:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard active false
setxkbmap -layout "us,ru" -option "grp:ctrl_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll,compose:ralt"
```

as explained here:

[Permanently set keyboard layout options with setxkbmap in gnome/unity](https://askubuntu.com/q/451945/181242)

Now, the keyboard indicator is not showing the current layout. How do I replace it with a working indicator?