# User xkb changes not permanent

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

So, base problem is I'm trying to invert my laptop's pgup/home and pgdn/end keys. Currently I have to use the function key to to access the home/end functionalities and I'd prefer it the other way.

So I found this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/188251/370442
Created a file like so (inside my $HOME):

```
.xkb
└── keycodes
    └── local
```

with contents:

```
xkb_keycodes {
  <PGUP> = 110;
  <HOME> = 112;
  <PGDN> = 115;
  <END> = 117;
};
```

and execute command:

```sh
setxkbmap -print | sed -e '/xkb_keycodes/s/"[[:space:]]/+local&/' | xkbcomp -I${HOME}/.xkb - $DISPLAY
```

Which *works*. The keys are mapped exactly as I'd hope. However, every time I restart my computer (haven't tried specifically logging out and back in to see if it's different) the keys have returned to their original mappings. I was under the impression that this was a permanent command.

I then found this answer suggesting that gnome might be resetting my xkb settings: https://askubuntu.com/a/582498/550300 but changing the key suggested there had no noticeable effect on restart.

That's my backstory, here's my question: how do I make the above command permanent? I was trying to avoid adding something to my .bashrc because I thought there should've been a more permanent solution without directly overwriting the xkb files or executing a script on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm then you may:

1. Create a new keyboard model file to replace `pc105` default model (or any other model uses `pc` file) with the custom mapping.
   I don't remember if it should be added somewhere in indexes found in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/` like custom keyboard layouts.
2. Set the new model in `/etc/default/keyboard`

***Warning:*** Reboot is required, verify configuration well before doing it. Or at least prepare plan-b (on-screen keyboard, SSH login,..). If there is a mistake in syntax, it is possible you end up with non-functional keyboard input.